# Grouping in SQL with a change in the column

Tags: sql, oracle

Finding duplicate records from a table

Hi I'm finding the duplicate records of a table using the following query

```
SELECT pm_no, revision,gen_date, count(*)         
FROM calendar_plan_tab 
WHERE gen_date IS NOT NULL AND gen_type='1'
Group by pm_no, revision,gen_date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The format of the `gen_date` is `'11/3/2003 8:00:00 AM'`. But when grouping I need to consider only the date of the `gen_date` column without considering the time field.

**Example:**

> '11/3/2003'in the above.

What will be the most effective way that I can try out this?

Comment: gen_date is string or date type?

Comment: it is in date type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truncating a date effectively removes the time element. But the columns in the GROUP BY clause must match the non-aggregated columns in the projection, so you need to truncate `gen_date` in the SELECT clause too:

```
SELECT pm_no, revision, trunc(gen_date) as gen_date, count(*)         
FROM calendar_plan_tab 
WHERE gen_date IS NOT NULL AND gen_type='1'
Group by pm_no, revision,trunc(gen_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

---

> " Isn't there any other way that we can select the original gen_date."

How about an inline view with analytic `count()` which is used as a filter in the main query?

```
select * from (
    SELECT pm_no, revision, gen_date
            , count() over (partition by pm_no, revision, trunc(gen_date)) as gen_date_cnt        
    FROM calendar_plan_tab 
    WHERE gen_date IS NOT NULL AND gen_type='1'
    )
where gen_date_cnt > 1
;
```

Depending on your data and your precise requirements you may need to use a DISTINCT in the outer projection.

```
select distinct  pm_no, revision, gen_date, gen_date_cnt from ( 
   ....
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Isn't there any other way that we can select the original gen_date. for an example another approach that we can try?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute like this:

```
SELECT pm_no, revision,to_char(gen_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'), count(*) 
FROM 
calendar_plan_tab 
WHERE gen_date IS NOT NULL AND gen_type='1' Group by pm_no, 
revision,to_char(gen_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Isn't there any other way that we can select the original gen_date. for an example another approach that we can try?

Comment: I dont think that is possible as per the requirement you have.
You need to group the data on date not on the timestamp and its the rule of sql queries that selected attributes along with the aggregate function field should necessarily be placed after group by clause